# topic subscriptions and token refreshes from the browser

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

let's say that the user has subscribed to 5 topic messages. Everything is working fine and the user is getting browser push notifications via their topic subscriptions.

But then the user refreshes their push token because they accidentally revoke my website's push notification permission.

What is the correct way to handle resubscribing them to their 5 topics with this new token? Do I need to worry about unsubscribing their old token from the 5 topics?